# A Swifty way of filling an array from a supplier function

Tags: arrays, swift

Say I have a function that generates random Ints: `func random() -> Int`

Is there a 'Swifty' way of using that function to populate an array of Ints? At the moment I have the following rather inelegant code:

```
array.reserveCapacity(arraySize) // array is [Int]
for _ in 0 ..< arraySize {
    array.append(random())
}
```

But it feels like there must be a better way than this.

Comment: Being critical, being curious and looking for a better way... +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `map` with a range:

```
let array = (0 ..< arraySize).map { _ in random() }
```

Comment: Wow, that is beautiful.